# react-slideshow-image package not loading images from google drive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, google-drive-api, react-slideshow-image

I've been trying for two days to make heads or tails of the react-slideshow-image package.  I've installed all the missing dependencies by hand, I tried moving the images folder around (anything outside of src threw an error immediately though...), and I also tried uploading my images to an external google drive and substituting their links for the ones given in the example.  I've disabled all other components inside the App.js.

Bottom line: the package only works if I use the image links provided in the example.  No other images are ever detected.

Here is my code (copied and pasted from the example):

```
import { Fade } from "react-slideshow-image";
import "react-slideshow-image/dist/styles.css";
// import images from "./images/homepage";

const fadeImages = [
  "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zAkmE3ZoXgYRjhylfRHCZKUJkUakCrfZ/view?usp=sharing",
  "https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Gz-fVv4hiKnfHgEPoLPZ02PlNQY3EYP/view?usp=sharing",
  "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B7WAX020SBZ1Bdq9TpC1ps0-XsdIJwWN/view?usp=sharing"
  // "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506710507565-203b9f24669b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1536&q=80",
  // "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536987333706-fc9adfb10d91?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80"
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="slide-container">
      <Fade>
        <div className="each-fade">
          <img src={fadeImages[0]} alt="" />
        </div> 
        <div className="each-fade">
          <img src={fadeImages[1]} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="each-fade">
          <img src={fadeImages[2]} alt=""/>
        </div>
      </Fade>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Original unspalsh image links have been commented out to see if my links work, but they don't.  Using images other than the ones provided seems to crash the slider entirely.
[screenshot of live server view of my webstie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVbwA.png)

App.js is rendered correctly, console does not log a sinle glitch.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
// import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
// import Carousel from "./components/main/Carousel.js";

// const divStyle = {
//   position: "absolute"
// }

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you copy this URL, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zAkmE3ZoXgYRjhylfRHCZKUJkUakCrfZ/view?usp=sharing in the browser, are you getting something? I don't see any image extension

Comment: Check here how to read files from google drive, https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files

Comment: @lissettdm when clicking the link I see the image just fine, will check out the guide and let you know, thanks!

Comment: You see a web page, not the image.

Comment: @lissettdm this is not quite applicable, as I'm trying to emulate what's been done in the example - get images by links in the source table (fadeImages).  when I click the link, I see the image fine, it's been set to "visible to anyone with the link"

Comment: This link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zAkmE3ZoXgYRjhylfRHCZKUJkUakCrfZ/view?usp=sharing, will open a web page with the image, you need to get the img src.

Comment: Try with https://drive.google.com/uc?id=<file-id>, example: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1zAkmE3ZoXgYRjhylfRHCZKUJkUakCrfZ, now you will get the img src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the images ids and use a different path to get the image url `https://drive.google.com/uc?id="<file-id>`:

```
const fadeImages = [
  "1zAkmE3ZoXgYRjhylfRHCZKUJkUakCrfZ",
  "11Gz-fVv4hiKnfHgEPoLPZ02PlNQY3EYP",
  "1B7WAX020SBZ1Bdq9TpC1ps0-XsdIJwWN"
];

const PATH = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=";
```

then:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="slide-container">
      <Fade>
        {fadeImages.map(src => (
             <div className="each-fade">
               <img src={`PATH${src}`} alt="" />
             </div> ))
        }
      </Fade>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that has indeed made the images appear properly.  Now I have to figure out how to change their sizes, as they seem to be immune to my CSS.